# Solidworks on Azure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks

Would it be possible to install solidworks on Microsofts cloud platform (azure) and access solidworks remotely. Actually, my computer is quite old and cannot install the newer versions, so i thought i could access it on cloud for the time being.

Comment: Any instructions for installation in Solidworks?

Comment: Don't think so, they have their own cloud service for accessing solidworks, but the price is quite high

Comment: I don't know about Azure, but i run Soldworks on similar cloud computing systems, like VMware and some other unknown services. I'm not very happy, because it's too slow.